# My PyPi package can be installed with pip but I can't import it

Tags: python, pypi

I've created a Python project and I've uploaded to PyPi using Twine.

The project is now visible on PyPi and I can install my package via pip with `pip install my_package`
However, after installing it, if in a new project I try to import it using `import my_package` I get the `ModuleNotFound` error.

I go to my site-packages folder and, in fact, I notice that there is only my_package.dist without the actual package... What did I do wrong during the configuration?

I used setup.cfg instead a setup.py , could this be the cause? I also have a __ init __.py file which I leaved empty (as it was written in a tutorial that I followed)

These is my setup.cfg and pyproject.toml files:

setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = example_package
version = 0.0.1
author = Me
author_email = me@example.com
description = example description
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/example/example
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Operating System :: OS Independent
[options]
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6
include_package_data = True
```

pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires      = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "example_package"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "example description"
readme = "README.md"
authors = [{ name = "me", email = "me@example.com" }]
license = { file = "LICENSE" }
classifiers = [
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
]
keywords = ["some", "tags", "opensource"]
dependencies = [
    
    
]
requires-python = ">=3.6"

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://github.com/example/example"
```

Comment: corrected "I also have a __ init __.py"

Comment: It sounds like `setuptools` couldn't actually *find* your code, and so built an empty package.

Comment: It was a filename error. I was named __ setup __.py instead of __ init __.py